# Wordpress - show number of comments for each post in widget

Tags: php, widgets, comments

I have installed a plugin that lets me put a PHP code into the widget - basically, what I want to do is to create a "recent posts" area, where you can see a cover of the post (featured image's thumbnail), title and number of comments for them.

So far I managed to create a code that works - minus the comments. I looked at few different things, like get_comments_number, comments_number, wp_count_comments - but so far I can't get this to work.

Here's current code:

```
<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => 3));
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($recent_posts as $post) : ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $post['post_title'] ?>
    </a> -  //here I want to show the number of comments
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Edit:
did it myself :D somehow my PHP stopped being saved and after a couple of more tries I managed to find a way. Added this and it seems to work:

```
<?php echo get_comments_number($post['ID']); ?>
```

Comment: Did you get an error using wp_count_comments?  What parameter did you pass to it?

Comment: Hey, just made an edit - managed to find a solution to my problem. But thanks for replying!

Comment: That is precisely what I was going to post as my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php echo get_comments_number( $post['ID'] ); ?>
```